# Missing form.type_extension.csrf.enabled parameter with SonataAdminBundle

Tags: php, symfony, configuration

I'm following the SonataAdminBundle documentation, so I've installed the Bundles and added them to AppKernel put now I'm stuck on the configuration.
I've used the basic config but I keep getting this error:

```
The service "sonata.admin.builder.orm_datagrid" has a dependency on a non-existent parameter "form.type_extension.csrf.enabled".
```

I've no idea what is this parameter nor how to set it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `app/config/yml` you should have a line like :

```
framework:
    #csrf_protection: ~
```

be sure it is not commented :

```
framework:
    csrf_protection: ~
```